# What is meant with naïve sign & encrypt?

Tags: encryption, email, digital-signature

In his paper *[Defective Sign & Encrypt in S/MIME,
PKCS#7, MOSS, PEM, PGP, and XML](http://world.std.com/~dtd/sign_encrypt/sign_encrypt7.html)*, Don Davis is often talking about 
the term

> naïve sign & encrypt

After reading the paper, I'm not 100% sure what exactly is meant with this.

Does he mean the possible habit of (mainstream) users thinking that sign & encrypt is an acceptable security practice? (Although there is no assurance about who encrypted your message)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The author seems to use "simple" and "naïve" interchangeably. Yes it seems he is referring to the act of signing (with the senders private key) and encrypting (with the receivers public key) the plaintext before transmission.

He views this as naïve because of the ability for a third party to forward a pre-existing signed message written by the sender to the receiver and the receiver assuming it safe to trust this.

Imagine a situation where Bob and Alice are attempting to communicate securely. Chuck is an untrusted third party known to both of them.

- Chuck sends Bob a series of questions for which he expects Bob to reply with fairly generic responses. For example Chuck asks "Did you read Dons paper?" and Bob sends back "Yes" - signed and encrypted.
- Alice sends Bob a message saying "Can I trust Chuck". Chuck knows Alice is going to do this.
- Chuck decrypts the signed "Yes" message from before and re encrypts it
  with Alice's public key. He then sends it to her before Bob can
  reply.
- Alice receives a reply to her question saying "Yes". It is signed by Bob and was sent encrypted with her public key so she trusts it.

Comment: I know this isn't a major point, but usually the malicious middle man is Eve, in addition to the normal actors Alice and Bob.  For someone who isn't used to the usages it doesn't matter, but when skimming over these allegories I generally look for Eve to see what she is doing maliciously. Took me a couple of reads to lock in Chuck was the malicious person here to understand the story (maybe I'm just weird and can't connect the malicious actions if I don't know upfront which person is being malicious)

Comment: @PunPun: Naw, Eve is the *passive* adversary.  Someone actively interfering like this is called Mallory.

Comment: @Kevin I've heard Mallory as well, to be honest I didn't quite know the difference.  I was just confused by choosing a C name which would generally be reserved for a third party with good intentions.

Comment: @PunPun1000 Eve = Eavesdropper, Mallory = Malicious Madman who can Modify your Messages.

Comment: (okay, maybe not "madman".)

Comment: @Kevin - [Wikipedia lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alice_and_Bob#Cast_of_characters) Chuck as  an malicious *participant*, as (presumably?) opposed to Mallory who is a malicious outsider(?).  It's not all that rigid, but I'd presume that Alice and Bob both know that Chuck exists (without realizing he is malicious), but not that Mallory exists.

Comment: @PunPun1000 - as per Kevins comment I was running with the WIkipedia definitions. Eve is usually passive. Mallory usually would not be a known participant. Whilst my example doesn't strictly need a known participant it simplified explaining where pre-signed messages were obtained from.

Comment: @PunPun1000 - in either case I've updated the answer to be clearer. If anyone would still prefer a name change i'm happy to do so but would suggest this is moved to chat so we can agree a consensus first!

Answer (score 3):

You should read the sign and encrypt scheme in the context of people in cryptography and security industry determining the correct order for combining signing and encryption into [authenticated encryption](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) to allow you to send a signed secret message.

The naive sign and encrypt is any cryptographic scheme where the message is signed by the author's private key and then encrypted to the recipient's public key in the simplest, most obvious way:

```
message = encrypt(recipient public key, sign(author private key, message))
```

This simple scheme has a number of vulnerabilities, as described in the paper.

The other naive orders: "encrypt then sign" also has a number of vulnerabilities. In the past, cryptography API used to expose signing and encryption primitives, but not authenticated encryption primitive, so protocol designers and application programmers have always had to reinvent their own combining mechanism, which usually boils down to either one of the two naive ordering and the way protocol designers and application programmers combine these primitives often led to unexpected vulnerabilities.

The non-naive sign and encrypt would then be any authenticated encryption method that combines traditional signing and encryption primitives with additional operations that interlinks the signing and encryption operations, to avoid the vulnerabilities of the naive sign and encrypt. This is as opposed to true authenticated encryption that are designed from the ground up to satisfy the design criteria of authenticated encryption.

This approach of building authenticated encryption from traditional signing and encryption is tempting because if it is done correctly, it allows you to combine any signing algorithms with any encryption algorithms, and it may make analysis easier as you start with well known, battle tested primitives rather than designing totally new ciphers. This approach also has precedents, with high level operations like PBKDF and HMAC being built based on existing hashing primitives.